# Обработчик onChange в textarea? как корректно записать в стейт?

Tags: reactjs, form

Есть компонент  textarea. его значения должно всегда начинаться со слова Hello.

```
                    <textarea
                                ref={this.textareaRef}

                                //defaultValue={'Hello '}
                                value={this.props.value}
                                onChange={onItemChange}
                            />
```

Я делаю обработчик handleChange и записываю value в стейт

```
    handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
        value: event.target.value
    });
};
```

Как мне сделать,чтобы корректно записывало и Hello? и оно не стиралось.

То есть в textarea можно было вписать текст Hello+ некоторый текст и он был в стейте?

Comment: нужно ли defaultValue,?

Comment: с ним работает некооректно